# Apple Airpod's have low volume when connected to Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: bluetooth, 19.10, headphones

I have been able to pair my Airpods to my Ubuntu 19.10 easily since I got them. However, the maximum volume on Ubuntu is quite quiet compared to the Airpods max volume on my IPhone or Android tablet.

Is there a way to raise the maximum volume without distorting the audio?

Answer (score 0):

Edit

`sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service`

and change

`ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd`

to

`ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd` **--noplugin=avrcp**

and run

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```